# How to disable the system drive paging file completely and still get dumps

Tags: windows-7, windows, minidumps, paging

Windows 7 Ultimate

I've been using the minimum paging file size on my system drive needed for mini dumps, but I have found that some things, like Hulu and YouTube caching still use it ALOT and it rarely ever jumps out to my main larger paging file on a different physical drive, unless I'm playing a game or have alot of things open.  The problem is I have an SSD for my system drive and I heard that having a paging file on an SSD THRASHES them.  So, I moved my dump files to the same drive as my main paging file.

Now, am I right in thinking disabling the system drive's paging file COMPLETELY, I'll still get dumps because I moved the dump file loations?  Will windows still automatically set up that temporary paging file on the system drive anyway (the size of the ram), and if it does, does it ONLY use it for dumps?  Or will it still be pounding my SSD?

**My goal is to completely eliminate the paging file on my system drive and still get full dumps on another drive, without the wear on my main system drive which is an SSD.**

Oh and I've read many similar questions here but none exactly like what I need, so please don't just start throwing "Duplicate!" and links at me, this is a combination of a few of the other questions I've seen here, but If I missed this specific one, please tell me of course!

Thank you.

Comment: Why did someone down vote my question?  I thought I asked it nice and proper, where did I go wrong?

Comment: Because I forgot to add a windows-7 tag?

Answer (score 0):

This is **NOT posssible**, because when Windows detects issues and Calls the Method to Bugcheck Windows, it writes the dump data to the pagefile (to workaround any disk related drivers) and on reboot, Windows checks if the pagefile contains dump data and writes them into the dmp files.

So if you want dumps, let pagefile enabled.

Comment: Wrong!  After a TON of digging, I found a way to hack the registry (as well as do a few other things) that worked.  It was a combination of a bunch of different answers to questions on various sites.  When I have time I'll get it all together and answer my own question.